# Complex exponential and the Cauchy problem $\begin{cases} f'=f\\ f(0)=1 \end{cases}$

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

How do you prove that the exponential function is the unique solution to this Cauchy problem in $\mathbb{C}$?

$$\begin{cases}
f'=f\\
f(0)=1
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Differentiate $g \colon z \mapsto f(z)\cdot e^{-z}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer What do you mean?

Comment: Suppose $f$ solves that Cauchy problem. Let $g \colon z \mapsto f(z)\cdot e^{-z}$. Differentiate $g$. Conclude $f(z) = e^{z}$.

Comment: You could see that if $f(z)$ were analytic, then $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$$Show from this that $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ and use this to prove $f(z)=e^z$ for $z\in\mathbb Q$ and then $z\in\mathbb C$ by uniqueness.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested, see that

$$g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{e^z}$$

Differentiate this to see that

$$g'(z)=\frac{f'(z)e^z-f(z)e^z}{e^{2z}}=0$$

$$g'(z)=0$$

Integrate both sides to now see that

$$g(z)=C\equiv\frac{f(z)}{e^z}$$

Let $z=0$ to show that $C=1$, leaving us with

$$1=\frac{f(z)}{e^z}\implies f(z)=e^z$$

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion of Simple art: $f' = f$ implies $f$ holomorphic, so analytic. Also,
$$1 = f(0) = f'(0) = f''(0) =\cdots$$
and the function is totally determined.